# Tropico 4: How do you level up character traits?

Tags: tropico-4

How are traits leveled up for the Competent, Specialist, and Expert achievements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the manual

> All traits start at level 1 and may be improved up to level 5 by
>   successfully completing missions and scenarios using these traits.
>   Improving a trait either increases a positive effect granted by the
>   trait or decreases a negative effect 10 imposed by the trait. Trait
>   level is saved automatically. Traits can never go down a level.

So it sounds like the key is to use each trait during a successful game.

Comment: Late comment on an answered question, but do sandbox games (not using cheats, but just playing a 50-year game on one of the islands) count toward trait increase?

Comment: @Shadur That looks to me like a question, not a comment. =)  I would guess the answer is no though, as there is no concept of "success" in a sandbox game.

Comment: You got to retirement age without being run out on a rail, lynched, voted out of office or deposed?